# XSLT is duping data

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSLT that is creating a data display that groups college course by subject, by degree and then by class.

Somehow the XSLT is creating duplicate data. Whenever the elements `<COURSEORAND1>` and `<GROUPORAND1>` are empty it duplicates that class listing one or more times (at least that is my guess). In some cases it creates over a dozen duplicates. The class only appears ONCE in the base XML.

I have no idea what is causing the XSLT to duplicate the data.

Here is the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- DWXMLSource="STX049-2-21-13-parsed.xml" -->
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:variable name="allSections" select="/CrystalReport/Group/Group/Group/Details/Section" />

  <xsl:key name="kArea" match="Section" use="ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1"/>
  <xsl:key name="kDegree" match="Section" use="concat(ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1, '+', ACPGDEGREE1)" />
  <xsl:key name="kDepartment" match="Section" use="concat(ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1, '+', ACPGDEGREE1, '+', ICCB1)" />

  <xsl:variable name="degreeFirsts" select="$allSections[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kDegree', concat(ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1, '+', ACPGDEGREE1))[1])]" />
  <xsl:variable name="deptFirsts" select="$allSections[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kDepartment', concat(ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1, '+', ACPGDEGREE1, '+', ICCB1))[1])]" />


  <xsl:template match="/">
    <CrystalReport>
      <Degrees>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$allSections[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kArea', ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1)[1])]" mode="group"/>
      </Degrees>
    </CrystalReport>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Section" mode="group">
    <xsl:variable name="area" select="ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1" />
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <areaofstudy>
      <xsl:value-of select="$area"/>
    </areaofstudy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$degreeFirsts[ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1 = $area]" mode="degree"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Section" mode="degree">
    <xsl:variable name="area" select="ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1" />
    <xsl:variable name="degree" select="ACPGDEGREE1" />
    <Degree>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$deptFirsts[ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1 = $area and ACPGDEGREE1 = $degree]" mode="department">
        <xsl:sort select="ACADPROGRAMSID1" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </Degree>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Section" mode="department">
    <department>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
      <Degreetitle>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ACPGDEGREE1" />
      </Degreetitle>
      <Certtitle>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CCD11" />
      </Certtitle>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
      <DegreeDesc>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ACPGCOMMENTS1" />
      </DegreeDesc>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;ICCB Code </xsl:text>
      <ICCBcode>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ICCB1" />
      </ICCBcode>
      <xsl:text> | Field of Study Code: </xsl:text>
      <ProgramID>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ACADPROGRAMSID1" />
      </ProgramID>

      <xsl:variable name="courses" select="key('kDepartment', concat(ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1, '+', ACPGDEGREE1, '+', ICCB1))" />

      <xsl:call-template name="CourseGroup">
        <xsl:with-param name="courses" select="$courses[FlagElectives1 = 'N']" />
        <xsl:with-param name="title" select="'Program Requirements'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="requiredCourses" select="true()" />
      </xsl:call-template>

      <xsl:call-template name="CourseGroup">
        <xsl:with-param name="courses" select="$courses[FlagElectives1 = 'Y']" />
        <xsl:with-param name="title" select="'Program Electives'" />
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ACPGHOMELANGNOTREQDRSN1" />
    </department>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="CourseGroup">
    <xsl:param name="courses" />
    <xsl:param name="title" />
    <xsl:param name="requiredCourses" select="false()" />

    <xsl:if test="$courses">
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
      <req-electitle>
        <xsl:value-of select="$title" />
      </req-electitle>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$courses">
        <xsl:sort select="FlagElectives1" order="ascending" />
        <xsl:sort select="CRSSUBJECT1" />
        <xsl:sort select="GROUPLABEL1" />
        <xsl:sort select="CRSNO1" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:if test="$requiredCourses">
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <credit-sum>
          <xsl:value-of select='format-number(sum($courses/CRSMINCRED1),"##")'/>
        </credit-sum>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Section">
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <Details>
      <class>
        <deptname>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="CRSSUBJECT1" />
        </deptname>
        <xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
        <courseno>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="CRSNO1" />
        </courseno>
        <xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
        <classname>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="CRSTITLE1" />
        </classname>
        <xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
        <classcredit>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="CRSMINCRED1" />
        </classcredit>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CRSMAXCRED1" />
      </class>
    </Details>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ACPGHOMELANGNOTREQDRSN1[string-length() != 0]">
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <totalcredits>
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
    </totalcredits>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CRSMAXCRED1[string-length() != 0]">
    <xsl:text> to </xsl:text>
    <maxcredits>
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
    </maxcredits>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ACPGDEGREE1/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' DEGREE')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CCD11/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="('CERTIFICATE')" />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is a sample of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CrystalReport>
  <Group Level="1">
    <Group Level="2">
      <Group Level="3">
        <Details Level="4">
          <Section SectionNumber="0">
            <ACPGDEGREE1>AAS</ACPGDEGREE1>
            <CCD11/>
            <ACPGCOMMENTS1>The Accounting program is designed to provide the theoretical and practical background necessary for supervisory and administrative careers in accounting and accounting-related areas. This degree requires a minimum of 64 credits in program requirements, program electives, and general education as listed below.</ACPGCOMMENTS1>
            <ICCB1>3203</ICCB1>
            <ACADPROGRAMSID1>ACCOU.AAS</ACADPROGRAMSID1>
            <CRSNO1>1150</CRSNO1>
            <ACPGHOMELANGNOTREQDRSN1>General Education - 12 to 16 credit hours (In addition to those listed above)  Total Credits Required - 64 to 70</ACPGHOMELANGNOTREQDRSN1>
            <CRSMINCRED1>3</CRSMINCRED1>
            <ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1>Accounting</ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1>
            <CRSTITLE1>Intro to Computer Information Systems</CRSTITLE1>
            <DEPARTMENT11>ACCOU</DEPARTMENT11>
            <ACRBLABEL1>CIS REQUIREMENT</ACRBLABEL1>
            <CRSMAXCRED1/>
            <FlagElectives1>N</FlagElectives1>
            <CRSSUBJECT1>CIS</CRSSUBJECT1>
            <COURSEORAND1>OR</COURSEORAND1>
            <GROUPORAND1/>
            <ACADREQMTBLOCKSID1>16316</ACADREQMTBLOCKSID1>
            <GROUPLABEL1>Group 1</GROUPLABEL1>
          </Section>
        </Details>
        <Details Level="4">
          <Section SectionNumber="0">
            <ACPGDEGREE1>AAS</ACPGDEGREE1>
            <CCD11/>
            <ACPGCOMMENTS1>The Accounting program is designed to provide the theoretical and practical background necessary for supervisory and administrative careers in accounting and accounting-related areas. This degree requires a minimum of 64 credits in program requirements, program electives, and general education as listed below.</ACPGCOMMENTS1>
            <ICCB1>3203</ICCB1>
            <ACADPROGRAMSID1>ACCOU.AAS</ACADPROGRAMSID1>
            <CRSNO1>1110</CRSNO1>
            <ACPGHOMELANGNOTREQDRSN1>General Education - 12 to 16 credit hours (In addition to those listed above)  Total Credits Required - 64 to 70</ACPGHOMELANGNOTREQDRSN1>
            <CRSMINCRED1>2</CRSMINCRED1>
            <ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1>Accounting</ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1>
            <CRSTITLE1>Using Computers: An Introduction</CRSTITLE1>
            <DEPARTMENT11>ACCOU</DEPARTMENT11>
            <ACRBLABEL1>CIS REQUIREMENT</ACRBLABEL1>
            <CRSMAXCRED1/>
            <FlagElectives1>N</FlagElectives1>
            <CRSSUBJECT1>CIS</CRSSUBJECT1>
            <COURSEORAND1>OR</COURSEORAND1>
            <GROUPORAND1/>
            <ACADREQMTBLOCKSID1>16316</ACADREQMTBLOCKSID1>
            <GROUPLABEL1>Group 1</GROUPLABEL1>
          </Section>
        </Details>
      </Group>
      <Group Level="3">
        <Details Level="4">
          <Section SectionNumber="0">
            <ACPGDEGREE1>AAS</ACPGDEGREE1>
            <CCD11/>
            <ACPGCOMMENTS1>The Accounting program is designed to provide the theoretical and practical background necessary for supervisory and administrative careers in accounting and accounting-related areas. This degree requires a minimum of 64 credits in program requirements, program electives, and general education as listed below.</ACPGCOMMENTS1>
            <ICCB1>3203</ICCB1>
            <ACADPROGRAMSID1>ACCOU.AAS</ACADPROGRAMSID1>
            <CRSNO1>1100</CRSNO1>
            <ACPGHOMELANGNOTREQDRSN1>General Education - 12 to 16 credit hours (In addition to those listed above)  Total Credits Required - 64 to 70</ACPGHOMELANGNOTREQDRSN1>
            <CRSMINCRED1>2</CRSMINCRED1>
            <ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1>Accounting</ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1>
            <CRSTITLE1>Introduction to Computer Keyboarding</CRSTITLE1>
            <DEPARTMENT11>ACCOU</DEPARTMENT11>
            <ACRBLABEL1>OFTI REQUIREMENT</ACRBLABEL1>
            <CRSMAXCRED1/>
            <FlagElectives1>N</FlagElectives1>
            <CRSSUBJECT1>OFTI</CRSSUBJECT1>
            <COURSEORAND1>OR</COURSEORAND1>
            <GROUPORAND1/>
            <ACADREQMTBLOCKSID1>16318</ACADREQMTBLOCKSID1>
            <GROUPLABEL1>Group 1</GROUPLABEL1>
          </Section>
        </Details>
        <Details Level="4">
          <Section SectionNumber="0">
            <ACPGDEGREE1>AAS</ACPGDEGREE1>
            <CCD11/>
            <ACPGCOMMENTS1>The Accounting program is designed to provide the theoretical and practical background necessary for supervisory and administrative careers in accounting and accounting-related areas. This degree requires a minimum of 64 credits in program requirements, program electives, and general education as listed below.</ACPGCOMMENTS1>
            <ICCB1>3203</ICCB1>
            <ACADPROGRAMSID1>ACCOU.AAS</ACADPROGRAMSID1>
            <CRSNO1>1210</CRSNO1>
            <ACPGHOMELANGNOTREQDRSN1>General Education - 12 to 16 credit hours (In addition to those listed above)  Total Credits Required - 64 to 70</ACPGHOMELANGNOTREQDRSN1>
            <CRSMINCRED1>3</CRSMINCRED1>
            <ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1>Accounting</ACPGAREAOFSTUDY1>
            <CRSTITLE1>Word Processing I</CRSTITLE1>
            <DEPARTMENT11>ACCOU</DEPARTMENT11>
            <ACRBLABEL1>OFTI REQUIREMENT</ACRBLABEL1>
            <CRSMAXCRED1/>
            <FlagElectives1>N</FlagElectives1>
            <CRSSUBJECT1>OFTI</CRSSUBJECT1>
            <COURSEORAND1>OR</COURSEORAND1>
            <GROUPORAND1/>
            <ACADREQMTBLOCKSID1>16318</ACADREQMTBLOCKSID1>
            <GROUPLABEL1>Group 1</GROUPLABEL1>
          </Section>
        </Details>
      </Group>
    </Group>
  </Group>
</CrystalReport>
```

NOTE: the XML is only a small sample I have placed a larger sample at this link: http://pastebin.com/Y4J2VDRd

I noticed that it only happens when it runs over the entire file. Shorter samples don't repeat. But if you check out my sample at Pastebin you will see `<courseno>1175</courseno>  <classname>Microcomputer Accounting</classname>` and `<courseno>1100</courseno> <classname>Business Mathematics</classname>` repeats twice and in the larger XML you will see that as you get farther into the data the classes repeat multiple times.

Here is the expected text output:

```
 AAS DEGREE
 The Accounting degree program is designed to provide the theoretical and practical background necessary for supervisory and administrative careers in accounting and accounting-related areas. This degree program requires a minimum of 64 credits in program requirements, program electives and general education as listed below.
 ICCB Code 3203 | Field of Study Code: ACCOU.AAS
 Program Requirements
 Accou 1140 Financial Accounting............................................4
 Accou 1150 Managerial Accounting...........................................4
 Accou 2205 Federal Taxation I .............................................3
 Accou 2241 Intermediate Accounting I.......................................4
 Accou 2242 Intermediate Accounting II......................................4
 Accou 2251 Cost Accounting.................................................3
 Busin 1100 Introduction to Business .......................................3
 Cis 1150 Introduction to Computer Information Systems .....................3
 OR
 Cis 1110 Using Computers: An Introduction..................................2
 Econo 2201 Macroeconomics and the Global Economy ..........................3
 Ofti 1100 Introduction to Computer Keyboarding ............................2
 OR
 Ofti 1210 Word Processing I................................................3
 Philo 1114 Business Ethics ................................................3
 (Total Credits)   35
```

Comment: in your XSLT I get the error "Variable allSections has not been declared". Please edit your XSLT. I think this phenomenon has to do with the keys you declared. Regards, Peter

Comment: Could you possibly show your expected output in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, an expected output would be great because when I run the transformation I do not see duplicates. Thank you!

Comment: Also as others are reporting different results it would be useful to know what engine you are using.

Comment: NOTE: the XML provided is only a small sample I have placed a larger sample at this link: http://pastebin.com/Y4J2VDRd

I noticed that it only happens when it runs over the entire file. Shorter samples don't repeat. But if you check out my sample at Pastebin you will see `<courseno>1175</courseno> <classname>Microcomputer Accounting</classname>` and `<courseno>1100</courseno> <classname>Business Mathematics</classname>` repeats twice and in the larger XML you will see that as you get farther into the data the classes repeat multiple times.
I'm using Oxygen and the parser built into Dreamweaver

Comment: FYI, the "OR" text in the expected output is not implemented yet. I'm trying to fix the repeating data problem first

Comment: Seems to me that in both the "Microcomputer Accounting" and the "Business Mathematics" examples you mentioned, the data isn't actually duplicated by the XSLT transformation. Rather, the sections appear twice in the input XML: Microcomputer Accounting: ll. 1255-1277 and ll. 1324-1346; and Business Mathematics: ll. 1278-1300 and ll. 1347-1369. In both cases, it's the exact same `<Details>` element twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the data does repeat multiple times. Thanks for reviewing this question. We are working on generating new data.